# Get scroll height or height of an element and not body selenium

Tags: python, pandas, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I want to find height of an element having class name rslwrp
how to do this:

```
stores_container = driver.find_elements_by_class_name('rslwrp')
```

I know how to get body scrollheight

```
# Get scroll height
last_height = driver.execute_script("return document.body.scrollHeight")
```

but how to find height of `stores_container`  ?

Edit this is how i initialise driver:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager

driver = webdriver.Chrome(ChromeDriverManager().install())
```

Am i missing some headers ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In python I would do this,

```
stores_container = driver.find_elements_by_class_name('rslwrp')[0]

size = stores_container.size
w, h = size['width'], size['height']

print (w, h)
```

Comment: @aryanknp : anyway you are using `find_elements`, I thought it was `find_element`, updated above. or `stores_container = driver.find_element_by_class_name('rslwrp')` you can have it like this

Comment: It will take some time to test i will accept your answer once it works for me , thank u for your efforts

Comment: Hello can u help me with one more problem ?

Comment: i am trying to click on pagination link but my request is getting blocked but when i use that pagination link directly with driver.get("https://www.justdial.com/Delhi/Grocery-Stores/page-2")  it works , can u tell what is the problem why is click pagination not working am i missing some headers i am editing the code , thanks for your patience

Comment: @aryanknp : looks like a new issue, Do you mind creating a new ticket  ? I and community would really like to help you. Thank you.

Comment: this doesn't work for scrollHeight

Answer (score 2):

`driver.execute_script("return document.body.scrollHeight")` will give you the scrollHeight of the body element. To get the scrollHeight of another element, replace `body` with `querySelector("<element>")`, in your case like so:

`driver.execute_script("return document.querySelector('.rslwrp').scrollHeight")`
In this case, `rslwrp` would be a class.

Selecting the element with Selenium will not let us access its scrollHeight. In the other answer, he is accessing the size of the element which isn't a property of it in JavaScript like scrollHeight is.

For anyone not familiar with JS/CSS , `querySelector` takes in a CSS selector inside the quotes, here is a small guide on how to select by element tag, ID, or class using this method:

`querySelector("div")` selects the first div element which it finds

`querySelector(".class")` use a period to select the first element with this class

`querySelector("#id")` hashtag for ID.